# Using rg (ripgrep): passing --files-without-match option flag

Tags: ripgrep

how would I pass (in interactive mode for **rg**) the `--files-without-match` flag.. There is no short option, and `C-x l` doesn't show a possibility either. I can do a `M-x customize-group` on rg to set it for the session, but would like a more imperative way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `M-x rg-menu` is your friend.

Here I demonstrate

- how to add new entries to `rg-menu`
- define your custom `rg` commands with `rg-define-search`

#### How to customize `rg-menu` (Variant 1)

1. Copy the following snippet to your  `*scratch*` file, and do `M-x eval-buffer`.

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'rg-menu
  (plist-put (symbol-plist 'rg-menu) 'transient--layout
             (append
              (list [2 transient-column
                       (:description "More Switches")
                       (
                        (4 transient-switch
                           (:key "!"
                                 :description "Files without match"
                                 :argument "--files-without-match"
                                 :command transient:rg-menu:--files-without-match
                                 ))
                        )])
              (plist-get (symbol-plist 'rg-menu) 'transient--layout))))
```

2. Invoke `rg` with `C-u M-x rg`. `rg` will run the following command

```
/usr/bin/rg --color=always --colors=match:fg:red --colors=path:fg:magenta --colors=line:fg:green --colors=column:none -n --column --type-add=gyp\:\*.gyp --type-add=gyp\:\*.gypi -i --heading --no-config --type=elisp -e rg-menu
```

***`C-u M-x rg`***
[image: C-u M-x rg]

3. Let the default search finish. You will get this

***Hits for `rg-menu`***

[image: Hits for rg-menu]

4. `C-x -b *rg*`, and press `m`.  This will pop-up a menu.  There will be a `!` switch.  Press it.  Then press `g` to start the search again.    This is what you will see.

***Select `!`.  Pess`g` to search again***
[image: Select !. Pessg to search again]

4. This is how the resulting buffer looks like ...

***Files that don't have the search term `rg-menu`***
[image: Files that don't have the search term rg-menu]

5. In the resulting buffer, you can do `C-u recompile` to see what command was executed previously.  You will see

```
/usr/bin/rg --color=always --colors=match:fg:red --colors=path:fg:magenta --colors=line:fg:green --colors=column:none -n --column --type-add=gyp\:\*.gyp --type-add=gyp\:\*.gypi --files-without-match --heading --no-config --type=elisp -e rg-menu
```

***`C-u M-x recompile` shows the search command***

[image: C-u M-x recompile shows the search command]

#### How to customize `rg-menu` (Variant 2)

1. Install the following snippet

```lisp
(rg-define-search rg-files-without-match
  :format literal
  :flags ("--files-without-match")
  :menu ("Custom" "@" "Files without matches"))
```

and you will get an entry like this

***A custom command `rg-files-without-match` defined with `rg-define-search`***
[image: A custom command rg-files-without-match defined with rg-define-search]

Comment: phew.. nicely done. The first option worked for me.. thanks! With the second "Custom" option, I found I would have to re-enter the query params.. any way to simply have it re-use the params of the existing query?

Comment: This question deserved another answer ... So added it here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74102/31220

Answer (score 1):

To  get this

***Add a header-line switch for `--files-without-match`; bound to `!~`***

[image: Add a header-line switch for --files-without-match; bound to !~]

***Results after pressing `!` in the `*rg*` buffer***
[image: Results after pressing ! in the *rg* buffer]

do this

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'rg-result
  (define-key rg-mode-map "!"
              (defun rg-rerun-toggle-files-without-match ()
                "Rerun last search with toggled '--files-without-match' flag."
                (interactive)
                (rg-rerun-toggle-flag "--files-without-match"))))

(advice-add
 'rg-create-header-line
 :around
 (defun rg-create-header-line--around
     (orig-fun &rest orig-args)
   (pcase-let*
       ((`(,search ,full-command)
         orig-args)
        (retval (apply orig-fun orig-args))
        (itemspace "  "))
     (if full-command retval
       (setq header-line-format
             (append header-line-format
                     (list
                      itemspace
                      (rg-header-render-label "nomatch (!)")
                      (rg-header-mouse-action
                       'rg-rerun-toggle-files-without-match "Toggle Files Without Match"
                       (rg-header-render-toggle
                        `(member "--files-without-match" (rg-search-flags ,search)))))))))))

;; (advice-remove 'rg-create-header-line 'rg-create-header-line--around)
```

Comment: Thanks @whitetrillium - I guess I had hoped for a simpler way.. but I really appreciate the update.